# Android - disable double microphone

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, audio-recording

I have application that records audio, on some devices(Galaxy S2) it records from both device and headset microphones. How do I detect such situation and disable device mic ?

Comment: Does this only happen when you use a certain `AudioSource`? Reading from both the internal mic and the wired headset mic simultaneously sounds like a bug to me, unless it was intended for some feature that I don't know about. How about if you specify a mono channel configuration for your recorder?

Comment: @Michael Hi , I have tried various `AudioSource`, but effect is the same.